# Loading Saved cookies in CookiesManager

Tags: delphi, cookies, delphi-10.1-berlin

i have a problem with loading saved cookies to CookiesManager, Error message : Invalid Cookies Date formate.
the saves cookies :
`ds_user_id=7459742257; Path=/; Domain=Testing.com; Max-Age=7775999; Expires=Sat, 07-Jul-2018 17:52:03 GMT`
 i dont know how to solve this

**UPDATE**

the error shows up because of the 10000 in `rur=FTW; Path=/; Domain=Testing.com; Max-Age=251879107499; Expires=Sat, 01-Jan-10000 06:59:59 GMT`
so i changed it to 2019, now it loads successfully,

```
     var
      S: string;
      Cookies: TIdCookieList;
      Cookie: TIdCookie;
      Uri: TIdURI;
      CookiesList : TStrings;  i : integer;
    begin
      CookiesList := TStringList.create;
      CookiesList.LoadFromFile('path\CookiesList.txt');


      Cookies := IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection.LockCookieList(caReadWrite);
      try
        for I := 0 to CookiesList.count -1 do
        begin
          // read S as needed
          S := CookiesList.Strings[i];
          Uri := TIdURI.Create('testing.com');
          try
            Cookie := IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection.Add;
            try
              Cookie.ParseServerCookie(S, Uri);
              Cookies.Add(Cookie);
            except
              Cookie.Free;
              raise;
            end;
          finally
          Uri.Free;
         end;
        end;
      finally
        IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection.UnlockCookieList(caReadWrite);
        Memo2.TExt := CookiesList.text;
        Cookieslist.free;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: What version of Indy are you using? If you are using the one that shipped with XE, you are using an old version and should upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Delphi Berlin 10.1 @RemyLebeau

Comment: Why is your question tagged XE if you are using 10.2? There is almost a decade between those 2 versions. The XE series stopped at XE8, there is no XE10. Please fix your tags. In any case, 10.2 has the latest cookie code, so it should be parsing fine. I won't be able to verify until tomorrow.

Comment: It's really important that you know what version you are using. It's no help for us if you tell us the wrong version.